# Swift NSData getBytes reversed

Tags: swift, nsdata

I made an app communicating with a device with Bluetooth Low Energy.
Basically, my app and this device have their own message syntax. They exchange data as bytes and each values in thoses data are reversed.

My problem is that after reversing back value, when I'm converting a 3 bytes value to an Int32, the NSData.getBytes function seems to reverse the value, so I have a wrong value. Example:

```
var value; // containing [ 0x01, 0xD3, 0x00 ]
value = value.reverse(); // Reverse back : [ 0x00, 0xD3, 0x01 ]
let numb = value.getUInt32(); // Numb will be 119552, instead of 54017...
```

I don't know if I'm clear enough on my problem, but here is my code. A function which reverse back data and then tries to convert data to int.

```
// Those functions are in an extension of NSData
func getRUInt32(range:NSRange) -> UInt32
{
    var data = message.subdataWithRange(range); // Extract data from main message
    data = data.reverse(); // Reverse back data
    return data.getUInt32(); // Convert to UInt32
}

func getUInt32() -> UInt32
{
    var value:Int32 = 0;
    getBytes(&value, length: self.length);
    return UInt32(value);
}

func reverse() -> NSData
{
    let count:Int = length / sizeof(UInt8);
    var array = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0);
    getBytes(&array, length: count * sizeof(UInt8));

    var reversedArray = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0);
    for index in 0..<array.count
    {
        reversedArray[index] = array[array.count - index - 1];
    }

    return NSData(bytes: reversedArray, length: reversedArray.count);
}
```

Comment: I don't get your `getUInt32`, why do you define the local value as `Int32` instead of `UInt32`? Also, is it possible that you are just looking for `.bigEndian` and `.littleEndian` which any `Int` type has?

Comment: getBytes with an UInt32 seems to have issues. I've seen some wrong values and the problem isn't happening since I convert like this. But maybe I'm wrong. This is why I'm here. I want it to be working properly :(

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the byte order utilities reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFConvertDoubleHostToSwapped

> You identify the native format of the current platform using the
>   CFByteOrderGetCurrent function. Use functions such as
>   CFSwapInt32BigToHost and CFConvertFloat32HostToSwapped to convert
>   values between different byte order formats.